# Is there a shape that has complex number of sides?

Tags: complex-numbers

A triangle, square, cube, prism have a number of sides that is an integer.

Is there any shape that can have $a + bi$ sides, with $b \ne 0$ ?

Comment: Is there a shape that has $-3$ sides? Is there a shape that has $3/4$ sides? Is there a shape that has $\sqrt5$ sides?

Comment: We usually assume that the number of sides of a geometric shape has to be a natural number (and often we also assume that it has to be $\ge 3$). But we could turn this question on its head and ask "what would it mean for a shape to have $a+bi$ sides (or $-3$ side or $3/4$ sides or $\sqrt{5}$ sides) ?" - can we define any of these concepts in a way that is consistent with our "usual" understanding of "number of sides". I don't have an answer to that - but this type of creative thinking has historically generated whole new areas of mathematics.

Comment: I think @gandalf61 has a good point. Why are the number of sides limited to natural numbers? Math expands beyond physical limitations and can have more than 3 dimensions for shapes. So why not an "unusual" number of sides? Why not 3.5 sides or $-\sqrt(5)$ sides?

Answer (score 1):

OK...every number is a complex number...because it has a real and imaginary part...when we call a number real then it is supposed that it's imaginary part is zero. Like-
$$4=4+i.0$$
And when a number is pure imaginary then it's real part is zero. Like,$$2i=0+i2$$

If you look through this window, then every number is complex.and of course you can say the number of sides can be complex..but I should also say that,**that** complex number(number of side) have to be pure real(integer)...means it can not have any imaginary part...

Comment: Is there any case in which you can have the imaginary part different than zero? Doesn't necessarily have to have a possible physical representation.

Comment: What is imaginary number? It is an imagination...but number of sides is in real world.It is like, say I had  1000$ in my dream.so,when I am awake I want to buy a mobile with that money...is it possible?